# Switch Statement Performance C#

Tags: c#, switch-statement

We're using a switch statement to do some processing on an object based on a bunch of conditions, with a default case that we expect to be called for all cases.

We're having a disagreement about the best way to approach this.

Some of us prefer example A:

```
switch (task)
{
    case A:
        ProcessA();
        goto default;
    case B:
        ProcessB();
        goto default;
    case C:
        ProcessC();
        goto default;
    default:
        Final();
}
```

Whereas others have suggested it's better to use something like example B:

```
switch (task)
{
    case A:
        ProcessA();
        break;
    case B:
        ProcessB();
        break;
    case C:
        ProcessC();
        break;
}

Final();
```

Since `Final()` will be called in all cases anyway.

Is this a case of personal preference, or are there objective performance differences.

Are there any guidelines or gotchas we should look out for?

This is being written in C# for an API, and will be called very frequently. We're keen to get it right!

Cheers!

Comment: I haven't EVER seen using the `goto` inside the C# `switch`.

Comment: I think first code should not even be taken into consideration. that's not what a default in switch is used for.

Comment: Yeah, that's wacky..  I prefer the second way, definitely.  Although the `goto` keyword exists in C#, I would stay away from it because it goes against the grain with respect to a procedural language like c#.  Also, regarding performance vs. stylistic choices: only address performance when it becomes an issue.

Comment: B is shorter, easier to follow and would be somewhat expected. `goto` shouldn't be used unless you really *really* **really** need to use it.

Also, this would probably be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Most likely the compiler will generate the same output for both so you shouldn't care about such low level performance considerations. Make your code easy to read and understand, that's the most important.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'll add that in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/06tc147t.aspx) page about switch, the `goto default` isn't even named (but the `goto case X`) is :-) In the [older version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.71).aspx) it is named...

Comment: Performance is really not a reason to prefer one over the other, readability and maintainability are much more important.

Comment: Since you're worried about the "performance"... please read and distribute: [performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: You can use [tryroslyn](https://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:master/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcBYAUHgB2ACMAbMAYxgtIEMQQYBhGAbzxk5iLMpgDcA9mAAmMALIAKSMhhgwASjYcuqkAHcwyCgAsY0xStWd2uY+er1UMAAwAuIxfNNBEEINKoAdAHUATlqoADKQqJI2CjhmThZQgsiCMCKoAGa0wKTIUTFcFFYwAIwO0TmqLm4e3v6BIRBhBZGOpTBxCZYg1gBM2aV5HTCdxc1lru6evgFotWGdjSXDrYnJaRlZTRbL6ZlDw5zlY1WTwaGSALQNPbvEfqi0ANaXxgC+ji+4T0A=) to see how the code will be compiled (remember to check even the IL version, because the decompiled C# code isn't always correct)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say stick with Example B.

There's really no point in manually inserting code to "Jump" around. Especially not when you're in all cases jumping to the same place. This is what code blocks are for. Example B reads much better, and is much easier to follow.

As for performance, I'm not sure which would be quicker (measure it?). But at this point it looks like a micro optimization that you shouldn't have to care about. In this example I'd say readability and maintainability trumps any minor performance gain you might get.

Comment: Did some testing with a few variations and the IL (and performance) is basically the same in all cases. Ended up going with B for the reasons mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score -2):

The example B is the best answer in any aspect.

Never use `goto`. It reduces performance and readability for your code. CPU uses some technologies to predict future instructions to prevent performance reduction. Using `goto` will disturbs this technologies which is caused performance reduction!

Repeating a piece of code will increase binary size of the program. So repeating `Final()` in all cases increases binary size of your code which is not pleasant.